# Multiple model one view and with another foreign key

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

I have 5 entity and use the custom model for the three of them but I need the foreign key of other 2 in the model the custom model are as

```
public class CourierRape
{
    public Sender Sender { get; set; }
    public Receiver Receiver { get; set; }
    public Parcel Parcel { get; set; }
}
```

The two remaining entities are `Country` and `City`

The controller is as follows

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
        ViewBag.S_City_Id = new SelectList(db.Cities, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.S_Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.R_City_Id = new SelectList(db.Cities, "Id", "Name");
        ViewBag.R_Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Name");

        return View();
} 

//
// POST: /Courier/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(CourierRape c)
{
        ViewBag.S_City_Id = new SelectList(db.Cities, "Id", "Name", c.Sender.S_City_Id);
        ViewBag.S_Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Name", c.Sender.S_Country_Id);
        ViewBag.R_City_Id = new SelectList(db.Cities, "Id", "Name", c.Receiver.R_City_Id);
        ViewBag.R_Country_Id = new SelectList(db.Countries, "Id", "Name", c.Receiver.R_Country_Id);

        try
        {
            SenderController s = new SenderController();
            ReceiverController r = new ReceiverController();
            ParcelController p = new ParcelController();

            r.Create(c.Receiver);
            s.Create(c.Sender);
            c.Parcel.Sender_Id = c.Sender.Id;
            c.Parcel.Receiver_Id = c.Receiver.Id;
            p.Create(c.Parcel);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            ViewBag.Message = c.Sender.S_City_Id.ToString() +" " + c.Receiver.R_City_Id.ToString() + " " + c.Receiver.R_Country_Id.ToString()  + " "+ c.Sender.S_Country_Id.ToString();
            return View(c);
        }
```

but it throws the exception and return the model with the 0 of the foreign keys

And when I remove the try catch it gives the following error

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Receiver_Country". The conflict occurred in database "452171974654368803C496909AE805A3_ENTS\VISUAL STUDIO 2010\PROJECTS\COPY OF ECOMMERCECOURIER\ECOMMERCECOURIER\APP_DATA\COURIER.MDF", table "dbo.Country", column 'Id'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Hmm, weird naming convention for your models. Also you seem to be manually instantiating controller in your Create action and calling methods on them. That's also weird. I would recommend you reading a few tutorials about the MVC pattern here before diving into it: http://asp.net/mvc

Comment: alredy done it its all about single model in a view

Comment: no, it's about a single view model in a view. There is an important difference that you should make between a view model and a model.

Comment: i need to show these three models in one view which i achieved it after this when i remove the relationship of the COUNTRY and CITY with SENDER and RECEIVER then the above code is executed well and gives the result but when i added the relationship then its gives the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the CountryId on the objects you're creating and make sure they exist in your country table.

Comment: yes they are existed and show in the views as a drop down list

Comment: also all the forign key are shows  0  in the view with in th viewbage when execption is trown

Comment: these keys are required in the Sender and Receiver models and are shown in drop down list to select it

Comment: You don't mention what or/m you're using. Try making the CountryId nullable.

Comment: the country and the city is the separate entities and there data is fetch from the database through parameters CREATE controller to the dropdownlist of the the view and then send back the selected one with the model return from the view